# Detect and set id and form name in script

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that a non technical user can update form fields and the form name which then gets updated automatically on a landing page.

I have additional functionality that I use which sets utm parameters in hidden fields which requires the form name and I also push the form URL through on a hidden field which uses field ID.

I want to get the HTML form name to get automatically set on page load, even if it has been changed and the field ID to get set from the form field name which doesn't change.

the following hidden field is used for this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="FormURL" id="fe580" value="">
```

I wanted to get the id - fe580 set based on the name - FormURL in the script eblow because the HTML name will not cvhange but the id can depending on the order this hidden field is in.

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("fe580"); input.value = location.href;
</script>
```

With the form name I would like to get this to automatically set on page load based on the form name in case it changes.  Below is the form name which can be changed.

Below is the script that I am using to set the UTM values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var defaultHiddenFieldNameValue = "NoData";
function getQueryStringParamValue(strQStrParam) {
var strURL = document.location.href;
var strQStrParamValue = "";
          if (strURL.indexOf('?') != -1)
          {
                      strQStrParamValue = strURL.substr(strURL.indexOf('?') + 1);
                      if (strQStrParamValue.indexOf(strQStrParam) != -1)
                      {
                                  strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(strQStrParamValue.indexOf(strQStrParam));
                                  strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(strQStrParamValue.indexOf('=') + 1);
                                  if (strQStrParamValue.indexOf('&') != -1)
                              strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(0, strQStrParamValue.indexOf('&'));
                              return strQStrParamValue;

                  }else{
                              strQStrParamValue = defaultHiddenFieldNameValue;
                              return strQStrParamValue;
                  }
      }else{
                  strQStrParamValue = defaultHiddenFieldNameValue;
                  return strQStrParamValue;
      }
}





var form = "SYSTEM_WEBFORM_WHITEPAPER";          //FORM NAME ON THIS LINE


function setCampaign(){
  var elqForm = document.forms[form];

  //repeat for each field to populate

elqForm.elements['utm_source'].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_source');
elqForm.elements['utm_medium'].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_medium');
elqForm.elements['utm_campaign'].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_campaign');
elqForm.elements['utm_content'].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_content');

    }

window.onload = setCampaign;

</script>
```

On page load both the id for the hidden field and the form name get set in the correct places.

I do not have access to the form code because this is generated by the platform a marketer can build the form in.

Comment: Your question centers around the need for getting/setting the form `name` and `id`, but it's not clear as to why you need these. Can you explain the larger reason for why you want this? Usually, coding for unique ids and names leads to brittle solutions and there are often much simpler ways to solve the underlying issue.

Comment: I want to automatically set the following hidden form fields on page load:

utm_campaign
utm_source
utm_content
utm_medium
FormURL.

The problem is that I do not get to have direct access to the form code because the form is generated by another platform.

Comment: Yes, but why? What are those hidden fields doing? There are other ways of including form data that users don't see than using `input type="hidden".

Comment: It appears as though you want to get the id for use in `getElementById`, but to do that, you'd have to get the element, so you'd already have the element and wouldn't need `getElementById`. Use `document.querySelector('input[name="FormURL"]')` Also, using `document.form[formName].elements[elementName].value` is just one way of getting a form element. Again, you can use `document.querySelector('input[name="utm_source"]').value` to set the value.